# Can GoogleAds.dll be re written for windows uwp

Tags: windows-phone-8, uwp, admob, decompiling

I know there's a admob GoogleAds.dll for windows phone 8, can we decompile it and rewrite by changing the adview control with some uwp control ? Will it be a violation ? Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: It seems it can not be used in UWP. From the [comment](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/issues/51) as jimper said:" Our library has dependencies on a number of types (namely System.Web.*), which are not supported by UWP. "

Answer (score 0):

If you already have ad boxes created before the announcement has been issued that you could no longer generate ad for wp from admob you can re-insert the code, but otherwise it is no longer possible, regards.